# Variable issue in GameMaker 2

Tags: game-maker-language

Making a game in GameMaker and I'm having a problem where the variable is not set and I'm not sure why. When pressing down on either W,A,S, or D and clicking LMB it works but crashes if I pressing down on W,A,S, or D then let go and afterwards click LMB.

Code:

```
var look
var bullet
if (keyboard_check(ord("A"))){
     x = x - 5;
    sprite_index = spr_west_hiro
    image_xscale = 3
    image_yscale = 3
    look = 180

} else if (keyboard_check(ord("D"))){
    x = x + 5;
    sprite_index = spr_east_hiro
    image_xscale = 3
    image_yscale = 3
    look = 0

} else if (keyboard_check(ord("S"))){
    y = y + 5;
    sprite_index = spr_south_hiro
    image_xscale = 3
    image_yscale = 3
    look = 270

} else if (keyboard_check(ord("W"))){
    y = y - 5;
    sprite_index = spr_north_hiro
    image_xscale = 3
    image_yscale = 3
    look = 90

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (keyboard_check_released(ord("A"))){
    sprite_index = spr_idlewest_hiro
    image_xscale = 3
    image_yscale = 3
    look = 180

} else if (keyboard_check_released(ord("D"))){
    sprite_index = spr_idleast_hiro
    image_xscale = 3
    image_yscale = 3
    look = 0

} else if (keyboard_check_released(ord("S"))){
    sprite_index = spr_idlesouth_hiro
    image_xscale = 3
    image_yscale = 3
    look = 270

} else if (keyboard_check_released(ord("W"))){
    sprite_index = spr_idlenorth_hiro
    image_xscale = 3
    image_yscale = 3
    look = 90

}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)){
    var bullet = instance_create_layer(x,y, "Instances", obj_bullet)
    bullet.direction = look
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR!!! :: ############################################################################################
FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of  Step Event0
for object obj_hiro:


local variable look(100001, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Object_obj_hiro_Step_0 (line 61) -  bullet.direction = look
############################################################################################
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stack frame is
gml_Object_obj_hiro_Step_0 (line 61)
```

I have reviewed the code multiple times and I am still stumped. Particularly because of the fact that it seems as though the variable doesn't save the coefficient set to it despite the fact that it should when W,A,S or D is pressed down then released.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you would want to assign a value to your `look` variable, as otherwise it will remain not set to anything if no buttons had been pressed.

Secondly, you may want to do so in Create event, as you probably want your character to shoot in last pressed direction, not just "somewhere"